# Typo at msdn page "C++ Constant Expressions"?

Tags: c++, msdn, constant-expression

It says at [msdn page for c++ constant expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ffb821x.aspx) that:

> Nonintegral constants must be
>   converted (either explicitly or
>   implicitly) to integral types to be
>   legal in a constant expression.
>   Therefore, the following code is
>   legal:
>
> ```
> const double Size = 11.0;
> char chArray[(int)Size];
> ```

At least on VC++ 10.0 the second line produces: "error C2057: expected constant expression". So is it legal on some other compiler or is the msdn page simply wrong?

Comment: g++ compiles this without problems.

Comment: This is legal in java : final double Size = 11.0;
        char chArray = (int) Size;

Comment: @Sar: But that's not an array.

Comment: This is also legel : final double Size = 11.0;
        char[] chArray = new char[(int) Size];

Comment: @FredOverflow:  Presumably because g++ by default supports C99 features as extensions in C++, and variable length arrays are allowed. VC++ does not support C99.

Comment: @Sarang: Why does what's legal in Java have **anything** to do with what's legal in C++? You used `final` in that snippet and that's certainly not legal in C++....

Comment: @Billy : its only because java made up from c++

Comment: @Sarang: Err.. not really. C++ was standardized well after Java was already being used. More importantly, while C++ inspired lots of Java's design, they are different languages. Java allows assignment of default values inside the class declaration, C++ does not. C++ has the concept of a separate class declaration and definition. Java does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to 5.19/1 :

> An *integral constant-expression* can
>   involve only literals (2.13),
>   enumerators, **`const` variables** or
>   static data members **of integral or
>   enumeration types** initialized with
>   constant expressions (8.5), non-type
>   template parameters of integral or
>   enumeration types, and `sizeof`
>   expressions. **Floating literals
>   (2.13.3) can appear only if they are
>   cast to integral or enumeration
>   types**.

From my understanding the code is invalid, while the following is legal :

```
char chArray[(int)11.0];
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not legal according to Standard C++. See 5.19/2 for the rules in the spec.