# Initializing a const int with a floating point literal

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

**Example**

```
int main()
{
    const int i = 1.0; // Notice I am assigning a double to an int here
    char a[i];
}
```

**Question**

Compiling the above code with `g++ -O0 -Wall -pedantic -ansi -std=c++11` gives no errors (except for an unused variable). However, if I remove `-std=c++11`,  I get the following warning:

> warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518787/typo-at-msdn-page-c-constant-expressions), I believe that in C++03, the code is invalid. However, can someone explain how the rule has changed in C++11?

(This question was a result of [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923615/compiler-bug-g-allows-variable-size-static-arrays-unless-function-is-templat/10924195#10924195) I answered.)

Comment: Did you mean to make `i` a double, not an int?

Comment: @Dave: No, that was on purpose. See the link to the previous question.

Comment: FWIW, clang++ 3.0 doesn't show the VLA warning. I don't have g++ to test it, but I suppose the warning doesn't go away if you change the assignment to `const int i = 1;`. Does it?

Comment: @jweyrich: Compiling with `-pedantic` on clang++ 3.1 gives a similar warning. If you change it to `const int i = 1;` the warning goes away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An array bound must be an integral constant expression, see 8.3.4 [dcl.array]/1 (same wording in C++03 and C++11):

> If the constant-expression (5.19) is present, it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero.

In C++03 an integral constant expression cannot be initialized by a floating literal unless cast to integral type, see the last sentence of 5.19 [expr.const]/1:

> An *integral constant-expression* can involve only literals (2.13), enumerators, `const` variables or static data members of integral or enumeration types initialized with constant expressions (8.5), non-type template parameters of integral or enumeration types, and `sizeof` expressions. Floating literals (2.13.3) can appear only if they are cast to integral or enumeration types.

This means that in C++03 `i` is not an integral constant expression, so cannot be used as an array bound.

GCC and Clang allow variable-length arrays as an extension to C++03, so it compiles with a non-constant bound, but you get a warning with `-pedantic`.  Changing the constant's initializer to cast it to integral type makes `i` a valid integral constant expression:

```
const int i = (int) 1.0;
```

With that change the array is no longer variable length and there is no warning even with `-pedantic`.

In C++11 5.19 [expr.const]/3 says:

> A *literal constant expression* is a prvalue core constant expression of literal type, but not pointer type.  An *integral constant expression* is a literal constant expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type.

The preceding (quite lengthy) paragraphs describe the rules for core constant expressions, but basically in C++11 the double initializer does not prevent `i` being a core constant expression, even without a cast, so it is an integral constant expression and therefore a valid array bound, so no warning.

Comment: GCC does *not* warn about the wrong integer constant initialisation. It warns about the use of the VLA compiler extension (which C++11 doesn’t use any more, since in C++11 the array can be initialised by a constant).

Comment: @Konrad, yeah, just edited it to clarify what I meant by "allows it"